# How do we access an output @Output on ngOnInit in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have dataServiceEvent output from Component B to Component A , How do I get or access the dataServiceEvent data inside ngOnit on Component A ? I can access it outside ngOinit as function but I wanna access it inside ngOnit  cause I wanna use the data from dataServiceEvent as params to getListOfDeals .

Thanks for any help or idea. Regards.

#Component A ts code

```
     ngOnInit(): void {
        //access the dataServiceEvent here
  this.getListOfDeals()
      }
    
    // I can access it here but I want to access the data on ngOnInit
      dataServiceEvent(item: any) {
        this.tableElements = item;
        // this.getListOfDeals();
      }

private getListOfDeals() {
    this.searchInput = '';
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log("getting deals")
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.tableElements.pageIndex + 1,
        this.tableElements.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.tableElements.sortParams = ['name'],
        this.tableElements.sortDirs = ['asc']
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          // this.dealsListData[totalElements] = res.items.length;
          this.dealsListData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.dealsListData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.dealsListData = res.items;
          console.log('res', this.dealsListData);
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

#Component A html code

```
 <app-table-multi-sort  (dataServiceEvent)="dataServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions" [tableData]="dealsListData" (tableActionsEvent)="tableActions($event)"></app-table-multi-sort>
```

#Component B code - dataServiceEvent is the Output from this Component To Component A

```
export class TableMultiSortComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() dataServiceEvent = new EventEmitter<any>() ;

  @Input() tableOptions:any;
  @Input() tableData:any = [];
  @Input() isClientSide:boolean = false;
  @Input() isLoading: boolean = false;
  @Output() tableActionsEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild(MatMultiSort, { static: false }) sort: MatMultiSort;
  
  tableConfig: any = TABLE_MULTI_SORT_OPTIONS.DEFAULT;
  table:TableData<any>;
  displayedColumns: any;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.initTableMultiSort();
  }

  initTableMultiSort(){
    this.tableConfig = {
      ...this.tableConfig,
      ...this.tableOptions
    }
    
    this.table = new TableData<any>(this.tableConfig.columns,this.tableConfig.sortParams);
    this.table.pageSize = this.tableConfig.pageSize;
    this.table.pageIndex = this.tableConfig.pageIndex;
    this.table.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.table.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.isClientSide);
      this.getData();
    },0);
    
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {   
    if (changes.tableData && changes.tableData.currentValue){  
      this.initTableMultiSort()
    }
  }

  getData(){
    //Todo: get totalelement, pageindex, pagesize from api service response
    this.table.totalElements = 1;
    this.table.pageIndex = 0;
    this.table.pageSize = 10;
    this.table.data = this.tableData;

    if(this.dataServiceEvent) {
      this.dataServiceEvent.emit(this.table);
    }
  }
```

Comment: e.g.: Before emitting the output you could save that value in a variable and access it from the parent using @ViewChild

Comment: Couldn't you just do this: `<app-table-multi-sort  (dataServiceEvent)="getListOfDeals($event)">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a property in the typescript of component A decorated with @ViewChild to get a reference of the component B (NOTE: the 'static' property of ViewChild was introduced in Angular 8):

```js
@ViewChild(TableMultiSortComponent, { static: true }) tableMultiSortComponent: TableMultiSortComponent;
```

Then, inside the ngOnInit method of component A, you can subscribe to the dataServiceEvent EventEmitter of component B (EventEmitter is a particular case of a RxJS Subject):

```js
// This property is used as the notifier of the takeUntil operator to prevent memory leaks in your code:
private _destroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.tableMultiSortComponent.dataServiceEvent
    .pipe(
      // switchMap subscribes to a new call everytime dataServiceEvent emits an event, and cancels previous calls, if any - You can use another RxJS higher order mapping operator depending on your needs (check: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/):
      switchMap((event) => this.getListOfDeals(event)),
      // The takeUntil operator is useful to destroy the subscription to avoid memory leaks once the component gets destroyed, you can use it for other subscriptions as well
      takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
     )
     // The subscribe was moved here from the 'getListOfDeals' method
     .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          // this.dealsListData[totalElements] = res.items.length;
          this.dealsListData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.dealsListData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.dealsListData = res.items;
          console.log('res', this.dealsListData);
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this._destroyed$.next();
  this._destroyed$.complete();
}

// In order to work with the subscription in the ngOnInit, here you must pass a parameter, which is the value emitted by the dataServiceEvent EventEmitter and change the method accordingly (I tried to understand it from your previous code, changing 'this.tableElements' with the 'item' parameter):
private getListOfDeals(item) {
    this.searchInput = '';
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log("getting deals")
    return this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        item.pageIndex + 1,
        item.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        item.sortParams = ['name'],
        item.sortDirs = ['asc']
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)));
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sir,  but why is that it is executing infinitely ? https://imgur.com/a/peQQrnK  , the getListOfDeals is infinitely being called and executed.

Comment: my question is why is it infinite is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923408/angular-ngonchanges-causes-infinity/68923957#68923957

Comment: are you still there @Sp814610 ?

Comment: Hi @LukeMycah, sorry for the late response, I've read again the code in your question, I see the dataServiceEvent EventEmitter emits a value in the getData() function of component B.

Comment: I am emeting the this.table as output cause I will be using the this.table like this.table.pageIndex and etc on component B, why is it always executing infinitely Sir ? what would be the solution ? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: Hi @LukeMycah, sorry for the late response. I've read again the code in your question, I see the dataServiceEvent EventEmitter emits a value in the getData() function of component B.

getData() is called in 5 places inside the initTableMultiSort(): in the setTimeout callback and also in the subscribe of 4 observables (nextObservable, sortObservable, previousObservable, sizeObservable). Can you provide more details about these observables? Maybe this is causing the infinite function calls

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwnod7 , this the full code Sir

Comment: or is there like a better wayto do it rather than Observables Sir ?

Comment: I tried opening your stackblitz, but I'm getting an error 'Import error, can't find files:
./table-multi-sort.component.html
./table-multi-sort.component.css', I think they're missing in the project files, can you please check?

Comment: I think its hard to make it work on stackblitz Sir because of dependencies and the data is from my API , I can only provide the code Sir and code snippets. Thank you.

Comment: The error is I think in initTableMultiSort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236429/discussion-between-luke-mycah-and-sp814610).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the event and access to its data like this

Component A HTML code:

```
 <app-table-multi-sort  (dataServiceEvent)="dataServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions" [tableData]="dealsListData" (tableActionsEvent)="tableActions($event)"></app-table-multi-sort>
```

Component A TS file:

```
private _eventSubject$ = new Subject();

get eventData() {
   return this.eventSubject.asObservable();
}

ngOnInit(){
   this.eventData.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
  })
}

dataServiceEvent($event) {
   this._eventSubject$.next($event);
}
```